# Unicode to Emoji on Android

Tags: android, unicode, emoji

given a `String` who's value is `"U+1F601"` (for example, it could be whatever other emoji), what's the proper way on Android of **dynamically** converting it to a visual representation of it's emoji counterpart? (no hardcoding allowed, has to be dynamic since this is server data). I know I can theoretically map it to `0x1F601`, but this is of no use since it can't be done at runtime.

I've checked all SO available questions regarding this subject, but none of the answers seems to solve my question.

Thanks in advance.

NOTE: Bear in mind that Emoji can be made out of N Unicode values (`U+1F468, U+200D, U+1F468, U+200D, U+1F467, U+200D, U+1F466` for example), and have skin tone modifiers.

Comment: It is rude to change the nature of your Question after posting, after Answers arrive, thereby making this existing Answers look in adequate or off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

There is nothing special about emoji. Each emoji is just a text character. Parse your text into a Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) number for that character, and build a `String`.

```
new StringBuilder()
.appendCodePoint( 
    Integer.decode(
        "U+1F601".replace( "U+" , "0x" ) 
    )
)
.toString()
```

> 

## Details

Replace the “U+” with “0x” in your input string.

Use `Integer.decode` to convert that hex text to an integer number.

Use `StringBuilder` to parse the integer as a code point for a Unicode character put into in a `String` object.

```java
        String input = "U+1F601".replace( "U+" , "0x" ) ;
        int x = Integer.decode( input ) ;
        String y = new StringBuilder().appendCodePoint( x ).toString() ;

        System.out.println ( x ) ;
        System.out.println ( y ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/2HPjCr).

```
128513
```

Notice that we did *not* use the obsolete `char` type. That type is now legacy, unable to represent even half of the characters defined in Unicode. Instead, use integer numbers for the code point of each character.

Comment: Thanks Basil. Although this theoretically solves the issue of parsing a simple emoji, it's incomplete since it doesn't account for complex emoji such as those with skin tone modifiers (ex. `U+1F486, U+1F3FE`) or several others which are emoji compounds (made of several emoji, ex. `U+1F468, U+200D, U+1F468, U+200D, U+1F467, U+200D, U+1F466`).

Comment: @mradzinski Then you should have asked for those. On Stack Overflow, we try to answer a Question as asked. I suggest you post a second Question regarding the more complicated content of your comment.

Comment: I originally specified "it could be whatever other emoji" :). But you're right, I edited the original question to reflect Emoji complexity.

Comment: And your edit is rude, disrespectful, and confusing. A second question instead would be appropriate. They are two different matters: (a) parsing the hex string of a character code point number, (b) handling code point combinations for character variations in Unicode.

Comment: You may be right. I originally gave for granted emoji complexity. It was not my intention to be rude, so I'll mark this question as solved given it addresses the original question. Thanks for your help.